# Repainting real-time data during a modal loop in a Windows dialog

Tags: c++, gui, winapi

The following code will start a timer to continue drawing real-time data (that has been pre-buffered, to be swapped in the gui as fast as it can) to the window during repositioning or inside a menu loop.

```
// State of the application
static bool running = false;
static uint32_t modalmode = 0, modalcount = 0;
static const UINT_PTR TIMER_ID = 1337;
static const UINT TIMER_INTERVAL = 33;

// Window message handling
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowCallback(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    uint32_t curmodalmode = 0;
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CLOSE: {
            if(running) {
                running = false;
                ::DestroyWindow(wnd);
            }
        }   break;

        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT paint;
            HDC dc = ::BeginPaint(wnd, &paint);
            // Buffer swapping / drawing happens here
            ::EndPaint(wnd, &paint);
        }   return ::DefWindowProcW(wnd, msg, wparam, lparam);

            // The following block handles modal modes
            // like resizing, moving or opening a system menu
        case WM_ENTERMENULOOP:
            if(!curmodalmode)
                curmodalmode = 1;
        case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE: {
            if(!curmodalmode)
                curmodalmode = 2;
            // Reset the counter and start the timer if entering modal mode
            if(!modalmode) {
                modalcount = 0;
                if(0 == ::SetTimer(wnd, TIMER_ID, TIMER_INTERVAL, nullptr))
                    assert(false);
            }
            modalmode |= curmodalmode;
        }   break;
        case WM_TIMER: {
            ++modalcount;
            // Repaint
            ::SendMessageW(wnd, WM_PAINT, 0, 0);
        }   break;
        case WM_EXITMENULOOP:
            if(!curmodalmode)
                curmodalmode = 1;
        case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE: {
            if(!curmodalmode)
                curmodalmode = 2;
            modalmode &= ~curmodalmode;
            // Kill timer if leaving modal mode
            if(!modalmode)
                if(!::KillTimer(wnd, TIMER_ID))
                    assert(false);
        }   break;
            // End of the modal mode handling

        default: {
        }   return ::DefWindowProcW(wnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

I specifically want to know if it's a good idea to `Send` instead of `Post` the `WM_PAINT` message to redraw the window, or if there are better, more idiomatic approaches in the Windows API to drawing in real-time during a modal message pump.

1. I can live with a fixed, lower frame rate (here around 33ms per frame) during a modal loop, since the user is probably occupied with positioning the window or reading through the menu. I can imagine changing the frame rate dynamically according to the cost of handling the GUI interactions, but that's not my concern right now.
2. Posting the message on the simulation side (pre-buffering) would introduce additional synchronisation (or alternatively flood the message buffer) that I want to avoid: predictable update-times is one of the first goals on the simulation side, the visual update time is secondary.

Comment: As a general comment: you almost never want to send *or* post a `WM_PAINT`. You normally want to call [`InvalidateRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002.aspx). This coalesces invalid rectangles together, and lets other messages get processed first, and then a `WM_PAINT` only when the message queue is empty (but maybe you're using `WM_PAINT` to force closer to "real-time" response?)

Comment: @JerryCoffin thats true, I currently force the painting of a child window, which simply swaps the opengl backbuffer going straight through: I don't use the invalidated regions there. I should probably move this out of `WM_PAINT` and into a separate call so I don't need to pretend I'm painting, when I only want to swap the buffers...